# Why I can't run perl from Textmate?

Tags: perl, textmate

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use WWW::Mechanize;
print $WWW::Mechanize::VERSION."\n";
```

1) run from Textmate :

> Can't locate WWW/Mechanize.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/Perl.tmbundle/Support
>   /Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0
>   /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0
>   /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.10.0
>   /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Network/Library/Perl
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0 .) at
>   /Users/xxx/Development/test.pl line 2. BEGIN failed--compilation
>   aborted at /Users/xxx/Development/test.pl line 2.

2) run from terminal:

```
sh-3.2# perl test.pl<br>
1.64
```

What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like it might be environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you installed WWW::Mechanize into a directory that isn't searched by default.  Most likely, you have a PERL5LIB or other environment variable that adds that directory to Perl's search path, and for some reason that's not set in the environment TextMate provides.

Try running `perl -V` from the shell and from TextMate and see what the difference in search paths is.  You can also add

```
print "$INC{'WWW/Mechanize.pm'}\n";
```

to your test script to find out where it's installed.

Comment: I known the problem now.
I have perl two version 5.10.0 and 5.8.9.
Textmate run from 5.10.0 but shell run from 5.8.9.
How can I change Textmate to run 5.8.9?

Comment: @ratchse: change the /usr/bin/perl to the appropriate path to the 5.8.9 perl?